# i2p : Depends: libjbigi-jni but it is not installable

Tags: software-installation, dependencies, arm, source-packages

I am trying to install `i2p` on my ARM-based board with Ubuntu-server 16.04(3.4.113-sun8i #16 SMP PREEMPT Tue Jun 13 14:15:57 CEST 2017 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux). But it says:

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 i2p : Depends: libjbigi-jni but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Are there any equal package for ARM processors? How can I find it?

Comment: Hadn't heard of this before. Cool! I looked on launchpad, but there's no support list. https://geti2p.net/en/ looks interesting, but I didn't see support there either.  I don't do redit, but https://www.reddit.com/r/i2p/ looks like it might be helpful.